# Perl DBI: connect to REMOTE PostgreSQL db still complains about local socket file

Tags: postgresql, perl, dbi

I'm trying to use `DBIx::Class` to connect to a **remote** PostgreSQL db. 
My connect string: `"DBI:Pg:database=asterisk:host=example.com:hostaddr=10.10.10.10:port=5432", $user, $pass`

`example.com` does resolve to '10.10.10.10', swapping both to the IP or having only host=IP all result in

```
 could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"? at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/DBIx/Class/Storage/DBI.pm line 1489. at db-access.pl line 26
```

On this debian I don't have or want postgresql, I do have `libdbd-pg-perl` however. And `DBI->available_drivers` says that I do have `Pg` (It didn't before I installed the library).

How can I find out what it's trying to do and do I need anything else installing? The server in question is configured to allow connections from `10.100.*` addresses which the machine running this code is on and I can connect to it with tools such as PSequel and pgAdmin on my workstation (same network) with the db user in question.

Comment: Are you sure that connection string is correct? Other questions here on the site seem to have `,` instead of `:` between the parameters after `database=name`.

Comment: No it makes no difference, would have explained DBI assuming defaults though, the socket argument for `host` if nothing is specified.

Comment: Not `,`, it should be `;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> "DBI:Pg:database=asterisk:host=example.com:hostaddr=10.10.10.10:port=5432"
> ```

That should be:

```
"DBI:Pg:database=asterisk;host=example.com;hostaddr=10.10.10.10;port=5432"
```

Only the first two separators are colons. The rest of them should be semi-colons.

Comment: Pff is that a PostgreSQL thing? I shamefully admit I've only used MySQL flavours with DBI where colons worked fine. (and yes I connected!)

Comment: The [DBD::mysql documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::mysql#SYNOPSIS) has the same thing. But it's possible that DBD::mysql is less strict about the correct syntax.